# Difference between Ubuntu Unity 14.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

This might be a silly question. But I come across the phrase "Ubuntu Unity 14.04". I wonder if there is any fundamental difference between it and the perhaps more commonly seen phrase "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"? Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is the long-term support release, and off-topic due to being EOL (14.04 or 2014.April release with 5 years of support has ended).  14.04 may refer to 14.04 LTS or 14.04 ESM (which is supported by Canonical, but still off-topic though)

Comment: Unity is the default desktop for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop version,  again Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without any further info may refer to desktop, or to server, or any of the other install options available - ie. which include non-desktop (no Unity).  The release notes refer to desktop, server, touch, and of course flavors - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS versus Ubuntu 14.04**

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is the long-term support release, and off-topic due to being EOL (14.04 or 2014.April release with 5 years of support has ended). 14.04 may refer to 14.04 LTS or 14.04 ESM (which is still supported by Canonical receiving updates, but off-topic here though)

**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with/without Unity**

Unity is the default desktop for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop version.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without any further info, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS may refer to

- desktop, or
- server, or
- another install option (netboot etc)

most of which do not include desktop (ie. no Unity). The release notes refer to desktop, server, touch, and of course flavors (where Unity was replaced by another desktop (Xubuntu had XFCE, Kubuntu had KDE, Lubuntu then had LXDE etc)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes